# Can't do basic integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I seem to be brain dead today, and I can't do the following integral:

> $\displaystyle\int \cfrac{1}{\sqrt{-cx^3}} dx$

Why is this wrong:

$$\displaystyle\int \cfrac{1}{\sqrt{-cx^3}} dx= \displaystyle\int (-cx^3)^{-\frac12}dx=(-cx^3)^{\frac12}*\frac{2}{3cx^2}+d$$

From comments:

$$\displaystyle\int -c^{-\frac12}x^{-\frac32}dx=-c^{-\frac12}x^{-\frac12}*-2=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{cx}}+d$$

Which I think is still wrong

Apparently this equals: $$-\cfrac{2x}{\sqrt{-cx^3}}+d$$

Comment: Move the exponent inside the parenthesis before integrating.

Comment: Your addition "From comments" is missing a minus before the $c$ in the denominator. If you correct this, then you will see that it equals the last expression you have written. You can always simplify integral expressions before integration like this to avoid those troublesome combination rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct. It is just in a different form. You(I) wasted about an hour on nothing.

Answer (score 1):

$$\displaystyle\int \cfrac{1}{\sqrt{-cx^3}} dx= \displaystyle\int (-cx^3)^{-\frac12}dx= \displaystyle\int (-c)^{-\frac12} x^{-\frac{3}{2} }dx= -2 (-c)^{-\frac12} x^{-\frac{1}{2} } +k=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{-cx}}+k $$

Sure, this is equal to your other answer. Let me rearrange:

$$-\frac{2x}{\sqrt{-cx^3}}+k=-\frac{2x*x^{-1}}{\sqrt{-cx^3}*x^{-1}}+k=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{-cx^3}*\sqrt{x^{-2}}}+k=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{-cx^3*x^{-2}}}+k=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{-cx}}+k$$

So your answer can be reduced a bit to this.

Comment: Why was the power reduced? Shouldn't it have been increased?

Comment: What power is reduced? As an example, $\int x^{3} dx=\frac{1}{4} x^4+k $. The power is raised not reduced

Comment: Because $-\frac32\gt -\frac52$ Hence you reduced the power.

Comment: Turns out my answer was correct, it was merely in a different form, so I spent over an hour on nothing at all.

Comment: You were right, I made a mistake with a minus. It is corrected now. And yes, this equals what you have above.